# Invoke JAVASCRIPT method from Shell Script

Tags: javascript, bash, shell

I have a OPENREPORT.js I need to call a function in that js.From Shell Script(UNIX)
Can anyone tell me HOW to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using a javascript shell like nodejs..? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells

Comment: It depends a bit upon what environment the openreport.js script was written for (browser, node, etc...).  You can execute javascript scripts on Unix using something like node.js.

Comment: I had writen for browser.Without node.js we cant execute the javascript from shell script?